# Update SQL Query executes without error but does not update my table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

The following statement should update my `WAIR` column inside the `LSX_DC_SaleEvents` table to a numeric value but it does not. It executes without error but does not update my table.

```
UPDATE LSX_DC_SaleEvents
SET WAIR = (SELECT WAIR = SUM(CurrentUPB*CurrentInterestRate) / SUM(CurrentUPB)
            FROM LSX_DC_Loans
            WHERE SaleEventID = 1)
WHERE SaleEventID = 1
```

The result of interior select returns the value `0.050993` which is what I would like to enter into my `WAIR` column on the `LSX_DC_SaleEvents` table but it's always staying at `0` even though the select statement below returns the correct value.

```
SELECT WAIR = SUM(CurrentUPB*CurrentInterestRate) / SUM(CurrentUPB)
FROM LSX_DC_Loans
```

Can anyone catch what I'm doing wrong?

The data-type for the `WAIR` column is `varchar` which is fine for my purposes I don't need a float can that be interfering?

Comment: what is the data type of your WAIR column?

Comment: @Kamran Farzami varchar

Comment: what are your other data types sum(CurrentUPB*CurrentInterestRate) / sum (CurrentUPB)

Comment: CurrentUPB = money, CurrentInterestRate = decimal 6,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the results are getting rounded because of your datatypes.

try this,

```
UPDATE LSX_DC_SaleEvents
  SET
      WAIR =
(
    SELECT WAIR = SUM(CAST(CurrentUPB AS DECIMAL(19, 6)) * CAST(CurrentInterestRate AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) / SUM(CAST(CurrentUPB AS DECIMAL(19, 6)))
    FROM LSX_DC_Loans
    WHERE SaleEventID = 1
)
WHERE SaleEventID = 1;
```

Comment: Same result, the `SELECT WAIR = SUM(CAST(CurrentUPB AS DECIMAL(19, 6)) * CAST(CurrentInterestRate AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) / SUM(CAST(CurrentUPB AS DECIMAL(19, 6)))
    FROM LSX_DC_Loans` gets me the proper info in this case `0.050993` but it does not update the `WAIR` column on the `LSX_DC_SaleEvents` table

Comment: can you change the data type for WAIR to DECIMAL or Float?

Comment: thank you the issue was data-type. I switched it and it does record it now. facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE LSX_DC_SaleEvents
SET WAIR = CHAR((SELECT (SUM(CurrentUPB*CurrentInterestRate) / SUM(CurrentUPB)) * 1.0000
            FROM LSX_DC_Loans
            WHERE SaleEventID = 1), 8)
WHERE SaleEventID = 1
```

Why not just do that?  Why do you have "WAIR =" in the sub-query?